# Haystack with mongoengine documents

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack, mongoengine

In a Django project, I have some mongoengine's documents to be indexed in elasticsearch.
For this purpose, I was looking for django-haystack which is simple, well-documented and widely used.
Unfortunately, haystack seems very linked to Django's ORM and I'm encountering some difficulties with Mongoengine (which is very very close to Django's ORM).

So, does anyone have already played with haystack and mongoengine ? Did it worked as expected ?
If not, do you recommand a vanilla use of pyes or pyelasticsearch ?

Thanks for the time spent on this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `pyes` to get data in and out of elastic search.  I added a `to_search` method to my Documents and used celery and signals to update the index.  I havent tried pyelasticsearch but it also looks good.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Ross. That was what I intented to do.

Comment: Hey @Ross, I am facing the same problem. Your approach looks good, although I am unable to understand what exactly is `to_search` method ? Have you documented this architecture / implementation somewhere in details from where I can learn more about it ?

I am currently planning to use Django & Mongodb with [MongoEngine](http://mongoengine.org/) & [Mongodb River plugin for elasticsearch](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb)

Comment: If I recall correctly the `to_search` method - converted the mongoengine document into a json document to be used by elasticsearch. Using signals I passed the document _id to celery on a change so I could update the stored document in elasticsearch. This was all before mongodb added a text search itself which *may* be of use for you.